# How do I write to a website/HTML Document using python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python 3 and I was able to read the code from my html document but I was unable to write to it. How would I go about this. I'll show you what I mean:

```
 import urllib.request

 locator=urllib.request.urlopen("file:///E:/Programming/Calculator.html", "r")
 transfer=locator.read()
 print("\n\n",transfer, "\n")
 locator.close()

 locator=urllib.request.urlopen("file:///E:/Programming/Calculator.html","w+")
 locator.write("<p> Hello this site has been slightly changed</p>")
 locator.close()

 locator=urllib.request.urlopen("file:///E:/Programming/Calculator.html","r")
 new=locator.read()
 print(new)
 locator.close()
```

So I'm to read to it but i can't write to it or change any of it's code. Why is this?

Also, I tried to read from an actual url website using the exact same code as  above but replacing the url and removing the write function. The interpreter came up with an error, and I wasn't able to read from the site. How can I read from a website too?

Note: I'm just learning, I'm not actually gonna do anything illegal I just want to become more knowledgeable with this kind of stuff

Also if I change write to append() it still produces an error

```
                         import urllib.request

                          locator=urllib.request.urlopen("file:///E:/Programming/Calculator.html", "r")
                          transfer=locator.read()
                          print("\n\n",transfer, "\n")
                         locator.close()

                          locator=urllib.request.urlopen("file:///E:/Programming/Calculator.html", "w+")

                  with open("file:///E:/Programming/Calculator.html") as f:
                   f.write('something')

                   locator.close()
```

The above is a piece of code suggested by another member ut instead of writing to the url it up with an error saying:

```
                Traceback (most recent call last):
                File "C:\Users\KENNY\Desktop\Python\practice.py", line 10, in <module>
                with open("file:///E:/Programming/Calculator.html") as f:
```

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'file:///E:/Programming/Calculator.html'

Ignore the spacing its just the way i pasted it. all the code should be in line up to the with open part where the f.write function is idented

Answer (score 0):

`urllib.request.urlopen` returns a file-like object.

These objects expose a read method, but should not allow you to write.

I like to think of it as, when using `urllib` it is like requesting the file as you would if you typed the resource into your browser.  You can't write to it.  You request it and it is served to you.

If you want to [open](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#open) the file for writing you can use the `open` method

```
with open('E:/Programming/Calculator.html', 'w+') as f:
   f.write('something')
```

The above example uses `with` statement which is basically a shortcut for manually closing the file when the code exits the with block.

It is similar to

```
f = open('E:/Programming/Calculator.html', 'w+')
f.write('something')
f.close()
```

@Lattyware posted a great tutorial on it, many [more](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) can be found online.  The [pep](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) outlines what it is for.

It seems like you might be confusing `urlopen` and the `open` command.

Comment: You might want to [explain the use of the `with` statement here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4).

Comment: dm03514. This doesnt work at all, the interpreter coes up with an error

Comment: @Ken "This doesn't work at all" is not very constructive.  What errors are you receiving?

Comment: I edited the source code as shown above to what you suggested and I've also shown the error that was produced. The other part where i just read the url comes out fine but the second part where i write to it doesn't

Comment: @Ken You didn't actually use the sourcecode suggested. You added a ``file:///`` in front of the filename.

Comment: If i take out the file part i get even more errors. bear in mind this isn't an internet thing its a html document i created